Laravel Livewire events not dispatching across two components
I'm building a Laravel app using 11.x and Sail on Windows. Let's say I've got two pages, /questions/{question} and /status. /questions shows the user a multiple choice question, and /status shows details about the questionnaire, such as what answers the user has already picked.
What I'm trying to do is use Livewire to update /status when the user answers a question. This app will be used on a dual-screen kiosk, where the end user answers some questions on screen 1, and a computer technician can see the answers being given in real time on screen 2. To be clear, these are two separate pages in two separate windows. The two components do not exist on the same page.
If I use $this->dispatch('question-updated') in the Questions Livewire component:

class Questions extends Component {

#[On('question-updated')]
public function doSomething() {
  // Some code here
}

// .. some other code here that calls $this->dispatch('question-updated')

Then the question-updated event is caught and doSomething() runs as expected.
But if I make the same dispatch() call and try and listen to the event in the Status component like so:

class Status extends Component {

#[On('question-updated')]
public function doSomethingInTheStatusComponent() {
  // Some code here
}

// ... this component does NOT call $this->dispatch(), it's only called in the Questions component

Then it doesn't work. I presume that's because $this->dispatch() only works on the same component (i.e. in the Questions component, not the Status component?
If I use $this->dispatch('question-updated')->to(Status::class), then it still doesn't work.
What's more, if I try and listen to all events by adding this to my page:
        document.addEventListener('livewire:initialized', () => {
            console.log("Livewire inited")
            Livewire.on('question-updated', (event) => {
                console.log("Event received")
                $wire.$refresh()
            })
        })

Then I get nothing. Livewire gets initialized, but no events are received. Switching to $wire.on('question-updated') doesn't work either. Both are wrapped in the @script blade directive as stated in the documentation.
BUT, if I dispatch a Laravel event using App\Events\QuestionUpdated::dispatch() then listen for $wire.on('echo:question-updated,QuestionUpdated') (as I have Laravel Echo / Reverb installed too), then it works.
If I add wire:poll="doSomething" to the root div, it successfully runs the function, so Livewire is working on the page, but it's just not listening to dispatched events.
So I think that $this->dispatch() is only working from within the same component, and adding ->to(App\Livewire\Status::class) doesn't do much either. I think Livewire is properly set up on the page, so I'm at a loss as to what's going on.
Is there a solution for this? I know I can use Echo, but that kind of defeats the purpose of having Livewire.
